# VWAP-session/Day based

Tags: python, stock, trading, indicator, backtrader

I have this code:

https://pastebin.com/n9QHrHN7

What should he do?:
This code should only draw the VWAP indicator for me, which it does!

what is the problem?:
The VWAP indicator is there but I want to use it on a daily basis. This means that the VWAP should always be regenerated at the opening.
So far it looks like this:
https://prnt.sc/7mK_6cfvumSQ
(Pink = VWAP)

So in this example you can clearly see that the VWAP is not session-based but considers everything as a session, which it should not do

Can someone help me please

I tried to build the whole switch principle by using the code, for example:
`def next(self):
if self.data.datetime.date(0) != self.data.datetime.date(-1):
self._vwap_period = 1

```
self.l.typprice[0] = ((self.data.close + self.data.high + self.data.low)/3) * self.data.volume`
```

paste in the class "vwap" but unfortunately that doesn't lead to the result I want.
I've also tried to do the whole thing with static times, which doesn't work either

Comment: Include your code into the question instead of using a link.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted, but somehow stack overflow doesn't allow it..

Comment: What do you mean ? Just copy/paste it.

Comment: No matter what i try:
Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.